# fps character does not move the right way for me but does for tutorials

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-2.0

I have a fps character which I am trying to move in the right direction, means if I look into the west so the "W" key's forward move shall not move in the north it must move in the player's facing direction.
My code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{   public Transform cam;
float heading=0f;
public float sensitiveity=10f;
Vector2 input;

void Update(){
    heading+=Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*Time.deltaTime;
    cam.rotation =Quaternion.Euler(0,heading,0);
    input= (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S),Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W));
    
    Vector3 camF=cam.forward;
    Vector3 camR=cam.right;

    camF.y=0;
    camR.y=0;
    transform.position += (camF*input.y + camR*input.x)*Time.deltaTime*sensitiveity;
}
```

}

So here the error is that a boolean value can't be used as a Vector2 but while the tutorials say that this is the way to move it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, boolean value can't be used as a Vector2

Try this:

```
input = new Vector2(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) ? 1 : 0,Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) ? 1 : 0);
```